# D3 transitions with multiple graphs

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I'm trying to add a drop down menu that selects which measure to graph. I have 8 graphs, all graphing the same measure but by different ethnicities. Below is the code, any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? Right now i get the error `exit() is not a function`.

Ok i've made some progress with the following, however it's still a little wonky. The graphs are changing but are going off the charts - the yAxis is rescaling to the max of all of the graphs, not the local one.:

```
function updateGraphs(newData) {


    d3.selectAll("svg").each(function(d, i){

        eachRace = d.values;
        svg = d3.select(this);
        yMax = d3.max(eachRace, function(d) { return d[newData]; });
        yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, yMax*1.25]).range([height/8, 0]).nice();
        yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left").ticks(5);

        line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function (d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y(function (d) { return yScale(d[newData]); })

        d3.transition().duration(1000).selectAll(".line")
        .attr("id", function(d) { return d.key ;})
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .attr('opacity', .8)
        .attr('d', function(d) { return line(d.values); })

        d3.selectAll(".y.axis")
        .call(yAxis);

    });
}

var svgContainer = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
    .data(data2)

    svgContainer.enter()
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 150)
        .attr("height", 400)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top+ ")");

    d3.selectAll("svg").each(function(d, i){

        var eachRace = d.values;
        var svg = d3.select(this);
        var yMax = d3.max(eachRace, function(d) { return d.app; });
        var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, yMax*1.25]).range([height/8, 0]).nice();
        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left").ticks(5);

        var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function (d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y(function (d) { return yScale(d.app); })

        svg.append("path")
        .attr("id", function(d) { return d.key ;})
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .attr('opacity', .8)
        .attr('d', function(d) { return line(d.values); })

        svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);


    });
```

Comment: `enter()` and `exit()` are seconary functions to the `data()` function. For example, you would use `data(someArray).exit()`. What your code does is attempt to call `exit` on several `g` elements. Try doing simply `svg.remove()` or `svg.data([]).exit().remove()` if you want to maintain the remove behaviour.

Comment: @JSBob mm thanks for the clarification. I want to keep `.exit()` for the interactive property, but i'll look into using them in relation to `data`

Comment: @JSBob I tried editing it and got rid of the `exit()` error, however I am still having trouble actually getting rid of the old svg's. right now it's just adding them

Comment: It is also just adding lines rather than changing the existing ones, now that I think about it... hmm i must be pretty off - although I could live with this

Comment: A possible problem is that if you're calling `svg.remove()`, this is acting on the `g` elements and not the `svg` elements. The easiest solution would be to do `var allSVG = d3.selectAll("svg");` and then `var svg = allSVG.append("g");`, so the remove function will act on the proper element. Another option would be running through each g element and using something like `d3.select("#"+document.getElementById("<elemid>").parentNode.id).remove();` which will remove the parent of <elemid>. Or sans-D3: `document.getElementById(document.getElementById("<elemid>").parentNode.id).innerHTML = "";`

Comment: As for the lines, instead of `append`ing new ones each time what you'll want to do is `selectAll` the old ones and change their `x` and `y` attributes to match their new values.

Comment: @JSBob Thanks for the input. I thought `svgContainer.each(function(d, i){` does `selectAll` the old `svg`s, because `svgContainer = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")` is that incorrect?

Comment: edited above - made some progress with transitions. Don't think i need the `remove` anymore

Comment: In theory it should work just fine. You could try changing the remove line to simply `d3.select("body").selectAll("svg").remove()` to see if it's the data/exit function that's messing things up. If not, you can also try debugging. For example, make sure that the selection actually contains all the `svg` elements or try encasing potentially problematic sections with `try/catch` to see if anything pops up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks JSBob for working with me. I've got it working with:

function updateGraphs(newData) {

```
d3.selectAll("svg").each(function(d, i){

    eachRace = d.values;
    svg = d3.select(this);
    yMax = d3.max(eachRace, function(d) { return d[newData]; });
    yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, yMax*1.25]).range([height/8, 0]).nice();
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left").ticks(5);
    console.log(yMax);
    line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function (d) { return yScale(d[newData]); })

    svg.transition().duration(1000).select(".line")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d.key ;})
    .attr('class', 'line')
    .attr('opacity', .8)
    .attr('d', function(d) { return line(d.values); });

    svg.transition().duration(1000).select(".y.axis")
    .call(yAxis);

});
}
```